# AWS Client VPN can connect but cannot access VPC resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-vpc, openvpn

I've configured AWS Client VPN so that I can successfully connect using mutual authentication (certificates) and I can access the Internet. Still, despite following manuals, I cannot access resources in other subnets in the very same VPC. I would be very grateful for any hints of what might be missing.

```
Client VPN configuration:

Association:
Subnet: subnet-0a51a9e6891ccee4f
Security Group:  sg-08649152e7b46e74a

Authorization:
CIDR (1): 0.0.0.0/0
CIDR (2): 172.30.0.0/16 (VPC private IP)

Route Table:
CIDR: 172.30.0.0/16, Target Subnet: subnet-0a51a9e6891ccee4f
CIDR: 0.0.0.0/0, Target Subnet: subnet-0a51a9e6891ccee4f

VPN Subnet configuration (subnet-0a51a9e6891ccee4f):

Route Table:
Destination: 172.30.0.0/16, Target: local
Destination: 0.0.0.0/0, Target: igw-55d21930

Network ACL:
Inbound:
100 ALL Traffic ALL ALL 0.0.0.0/0 ALLOW
1000 ALL Traffic ALL ALL 172.30.0.0/16 ALLOW

Outbound:
100 ALL Traffic ALL ALL 0.0.0.0/0 ALLOW
1000 ALL Traffic ALL ALL 172.30.0.0/16 ALLOW

VPN Security Group: (sg-08649152e7b46e74a)
Inbound:
All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0 
All traffic All All 172.30.0.0/16
All traffic All All sg-08649152e7b46e74a

Outbound:
All traffic All All 172.30.0.0/16
All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0
All traffic All All sg-08649152e7b46e74a
```

Client is able to connect and gets assigned IP, e.g. 172.30.8.98.

Still I cannot access EC2 instance (in this scenario this is mongodb on port 27017) which is protected by a Security Group even though I allow traffic from the aforementioned VPN Security Group (sg-08649152e7b46e74a).

Comment: Did you ever resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of this will help:

1. SG associated with subnet is useful only for internet access - add 0.0.0.0/0 and forget about it (unless someone want to enlighten me after). Now that you want to connect to mongo EC2, add a rule to its SG to allow 27017 from sg-08649152e7b46e74a
2. You are trying to connect to EC2 public IP instead of private IP

Answer (score 0):

In had the exact same problem,  I had to amend the OpenVPN configuration file with the following routes.

```
VPC CIDR : 192.168.0.0/16
Routes for OpenVPN Configuration File :
route-nopull
route 192.16.0.0 255.255.0.0
dhcp-option DNS 192.168.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the final step required was to add an authorization rule to my end client vpn endpoint.  The whole vpn endpoint creation process gives you the impression it's fully automated; e.g. when you're creating the endpoint you choose the vpc & the subnet you want to associate with.  And for the most part it does; route tables etc were all good.

E.g. I have a client vpn end point on one CIDR, a VPC with a private subnet on another CIDR, An ec2 instance in that private subnet.

Adding an authorization rule to the vpn client end point to allow anyone (or a group) access to the private subnet CIDR was the last step required.